# Where to stock key used for token generation in email confirmation

Tags: python, flask, pynacl

I have this source code in ruby:

[Ruby code](https://github.com/ISS-Security/configshare-app/blob/master/lib/secure_message.rb)

I am trying to build an approximately similar class.
I have this endpoint:

```
@register_endpoint.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def process_signup_form():
    form = InitializeAccountForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        email = form.email.data
        first_name = form.first_name.data
        # TODO add exception if the email doesn't land
        response = verify_email_account(first_name, email)
        return render_template("auth/register.html", form=form)
    else:
        return render_template("auth/register.html", form=form)
```

That send an email with a link including a token generated using this class:

```
class SecureMessage:

    def __init__(self):
        self.key = nacl.utils.random(nacl.secret.SecretBox.KEY_SIZE)

    def encrypt(self, message):
        if message:
            box = nacl.secret.SecretBox(self.key)
            cypher_text = box.encrypt(bytes(message, "utf-8"))
            encoded_cypher_text = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(cypher_text)
            return encoded_cypher_text
        else:
            return None

    def decrypt(self, token64):
        if token64:
            token = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(token64)
            box = nacl.secret.SecretBox(self.key)
            decrypted_token = box.decrypt(token)
            return decrypted_token
        else:
            return None
```

And I have another endpoint that is suppose to decrypt the previously generated token:

```
@register_endpoint.route('/<string:token>', methods=['GET'])
def display_register_form(token):
    error = None
    decrypted_token = SecureMessage().decrypt(token)
    form = RegisterAccountForm(decrypted_token)
    return render_template("auth/register.html", form=form, error=error)
```

I don't really know where to store my secret key in my flask environnement, neither where the key is store in the ruby code.

Could you tell me what is the best and secure way to store my key?

**EDIT:**

I have the following flow:

1. The user signup by filling: first_name, email on /register_account
2. I encrypt using a symmetric key the JSON: {"first_name": first_name, "email": email} (it give me a URL_SAFE token
3. I send to the user via email a link /register/
4. When the user click on the email, we retrieve the token in the URL decrypt it using the same previous symmetric key and pre-fill the first name and email field, then the user can fill fields like password etc..
5. We store the user

My question is how can I store the symmetric key used in my encryption/decryption process?

Comment: With store you mean a persistence layer or only in the session of the current request?

Comment: @LuisOrduz I edit my question to be moire specific

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to add two fields to your user table,

1. `verfied`
2. `verified_token`

Save your generated token to `verified_token`. And when user verifies email address, set `verified` to `true`.

Comment: I don't want to save the user in my database if he didn't confirm his account. So my flow is like: the user signup with his first_name and email, I encrypt the resulting JSON with a symmetric key and generate a token out of it. The token is send in a link via email. The user click on the link and then the token in the URL will be decrypted using the previous symmetric key, to pre fill the field first_name and email, then the user will be able to fill other fields like password etc..  when the user post this request. I create an account. My question is how to store the symmetric key.